# QT Design button disabled

Tags: qt, user-interface

I am new to QT and currently try to make a GUI.

For some reason the Design Button is disabled.

How can I enable it?

[Here's the picture of how the button looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjgHg.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double click form.ui file in the project if you have created.

Comment: I was able to make it work, thanks! Add new UI file by New File or Project >  QT > QT Designer Form